# ObservableArray not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am very new to knockout.js (just picked it up yesterday), but I was suggested it for what I'm trying to do.

My dilemma is this:

- i set the following "initialData" as a json array:

  ```
  var initialData = [
  {
      id: 0,
      pcName: "Test1"
  },
  {
      id: 1,
      pcName: "Test2"
  },
  {
      id: 2,
      pcName: "Test3"
  },
  {
      id: 3,
      pcName: "Test4"
  },
  {
      id: 4,
      pcName: "Test5"
  }
  ];
  ```
- followed by the following (simple) model:

  ```
  var PCModel = function (pcs) {
  var self = this;

  self.pcsList = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(pcs, function (pc) {
      return { id: pc.id, pcName: pc.pcName };
  }));
  ```
- and apply my bindings as such:

  ```
  ko.applyBindings(new PCModel(initialData));
  ```
- i then try to loop through my (what should be) `pcsList`:

  ```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="sortable" data-bind="foreach: pcsList">

      <li>
          <a data-bind="attr: {href: '#' + id}, text: pcName"></a>
      </li>
  </ul>
  ```

And yet, nothing seems to happen. I cant seem to figure out why.

Please help.

Comment: You only have syntax errors. Aside from that, see: https://jsfiddle.net/fwekz6mt/

Comment: Well. It seems that you're right.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to point out the syntax error(s)? I'm on my phone and I have to flip back and forth to check the code and I'm losing my mind looking at the fiddle and my question. Also feel free to post this as an answer, after all, you DID answer the question.

Comment: You're missing `))` at the end of the line starting with `self.pcsList`

Comment: Also, it might be that you're not closing the `function` referenced by `PCModel`

Comment: Damn. I do believe I have that in my actual code. I hastily wrote this question as I was leaving my house. But I'm nearly certain that wouldn't be the problem. So who knows. I'll find out tonight.

Comment: Be sure to check the console for errors

Comment: Yeah, from the testing I've done, the console didn't throw me any errors. I'm away from my PC now, so I'm afraid I can't give any more info. Thanks for the help though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131431/discussion-between-cristian-c-and-haim770).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone that may stumble around here, my problem was simply not calling `applyBindings` AFTER the document was ready. wrapping it in `$("document").ready(...` solved the problem.